# How to call Delphi Procedure from JavaScript code in TMS WEB Core?

Tags: javascript, delphi, procedure, tms, tms-web-core

I want to call/execute a Delphi procedure via my JavaScript code, but I'm not sure how.

I have my procedure declared as a public procedure within my form's class declaration like this:

```
TfrmMain = class(TWebForm)
  ...
private
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
  procedure MyDelphiProcedure(MyParam: UInt64);
end;
```

And then somewhere on my web page, I have an HTML Image with an `onClick` event attached to it. I'd like to call my Delphi function from that onClick event, but how? This HTML image is not linked to any Delphi component. It's just a standalone HTML image that is dynamically created using JavaScript.

Also, it's not specific to the `onClick` of the image. I want to be able to call the procedure from anywhere in JavaScript on my page.

Just simply doing `MyDelphiProcedure(1);` fails. Doing `this.MyDelphiProcedure(1);` also fails.

How can I access my form and call the Delphi function from JavaScript?

Comment: Most likely you can't, since JS would neither know about data types like `UInt64`, nor about potential `var` parameters - if at all I guess only `Variant`s may be possible. How did you access your `TFrmMain` previously in JS?

Comment: @AmigoJack JavaScript doesn't care about the type. So it doesn't care if it's `UInt64` or something else. That is just for if you use the function within Delphi. The compiled function actually looks like this: `this.MyDelphiProcedure = function (MyParam) {}`.

Comment: @AmigoJack Also, I know it's possible, because I've been able to do this before. But I don't remember how and can't seem to get it working now. Also even though I managed to get it working last time, it was calling the procedure, but the procedure weren't able to access private declarations from the form. So before I wasn't doing it correct either probably.